# Is Acetyl L-Carnitine effective for weight loss?

Tags: weight-loss

How effective is Acetyle L-Carnitine for losing weight?  Basically If one were to take this before an exercise routine, would they burn more fat during that routine, as opposed to not taking it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* your answer would be no, as I understand how L-Carnitine works in the body. ALCAR is an acetylated version of l-carnitine, and it occurs naturally, as well as the body creating it's own as needed.

Ingesting it already acetylated can enhance the availability of it in the body. It's a little confusing in how it shuffles in and out of the cells, and it gets converted to l-carnitine then moved back into the cell with acyl groups.

In theory, it helps promote higher utilization of fatty acids at the expense of glucose, but high amounts of CoA (Coenzyme A) can block it, and ALCAR does promote higher glucose utilization (Which, theoretically, would prevent said glucose from being converted for storage).

Bottom line, it's possible it might help, but in my personal opinion, the possibility is slim enough I'd rather eat a healthy diet and let my body convert l-carnitine to ALCAR naturally (Which it does do).